Beginners question : proof about ideal generated by a finite set.
Objective: Let $R$ be a ring. Let $X$ be a finite subset of $R$.Prove that $(X)$$=(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})$$= \{\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_{i}x_{i}s_{i}|x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\in X, r_{1},\dots,r_{n},s_{1},\dots,s_{n}\in R\}$.
I managed to prove that $(X) = \{\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_{i}x_{i}| r_{i} \in R, x_{i} \in X \ \forall i\} = A$ and $(X) = \{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}s_{i}| s_{i} \in R, x_{i} \in X \ \forall i\} = B$ and that $A$ and $B$ are both ideals of $R$ that contain $X$. But I don't know how to prove that $(X) = \{\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_{i}x_{i}s_{i}| x_{1},...,x_{n} \in X, r_{1},..,r_{n},s_{1},...,s_{n} \in R \}$.
My lecture notes mention that the empty sum equals zero. I aim to prove this statement because it seems important in demonstrating several properties of $(X)$, including the fact that $(X)$ is the smallest ideal of $R$ containing $X$.

Your claims about $A$ and $B$ are incorrect unless you are assuming that $R$ is commutative. If $R$ is not commutative, then in general neither $A$ nor $B$ are ideals; $A$ is a left ideal and $B$ is a right ideal.

That the empty sum is equal to zero is a definition, not a statement to be proven.

@ArturoMagidin i’m not assuming R is commutative, so thanks.

To prove the desired equality, show that the given set is an ideal, and show that any ideal that contains $X$ must contain every element of the form $rxs$ with $r,s\in R$ and $x\in X$, and deduce it must contain $(X)$.
